# JavaScript - Animated rotation algorithm

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation, trigonometry, radians

I just wrote a piece of code to handle object rotation in a THREE.js scene. The problem is not 3D-specific though.

I want my object (this) to turn by 0.25 radians upon each function call until it's rotation (this.clientRotation) reaches the rotation defined in this.targetRotation. The code below is the content of an update() function which gets called continuously in the rendering loop.

I had to check if the absolute difference between the current and target rotation is above the rotation amount for each call (0.25) to avoid back and forth turning once the target rotation is almost reached.

I had to check if the rotation (in radians) difference is above 180 degrees in which case the shortest turn would be the other way around.

I had to check if the updated rotation stays between -PI and +PI (0 and 360 degrees).

```
//Move only if we find a delta big enough between the target rotation and current rotation
//Rotation goes from -PI to +PI
this.rotationSpeed = 0.25;

var absDiff = Math.abs(this.clientRotation - this.targetRotation);
if(absDiff > this.rotationSpeed){

  if(absDiff < Math.PI){

    //Less than 180 degrees, turn towards the target
    if(this.targetRotation > this.clientRotation) this.clientRotation += this.rotationSpeed;
    if(this.targetRotation < this.clientRotation) this.clientRotation -= this.rotationSpeed;
  } else {

    //More than 180 degrees this way, so it is shorter to turn the other way
    if(this.targetRotation > this.clientRotation) this.clientRotation -= this.rotationSpeed;
    if(this.targetRotation < this.clientRotation) this.clientRotation += this.rotationSpeed;
  }

  //If rotation radians becomes more than a complete 360 turn, start again from 0
//If it goes below 0, start again down from 360
  if(this.clientRotation > Math.PI) this.clientRotation -= Math.PI*2;
  if(this.clientRotation < -Math.PI) this.clientRotation += Math.PI*2;
}
```

It works but it seems overly complicated. Is there a more optimized way of achieving this standard rotation behavior ?

Answer (score 2):

The code below is functionally the same just using ternaries to condense the logic. IMO it is much easier to read, but it is completely preference.

```
this.rotationSpeed = 0.25;
var absDiff = Math.abs(this.clientRotation - this.targetRotation);
if(absDiff > this.rotationSpeed) {
  var lessThan180 = absDiff < Math.PI;
  if(this.targetRotation > this.clientRotation) {
    this.clientRotation = (lessThan180) ? this.clientRotation + this.rotationSpeed : this.clientRotation - this.rotationSpeed;
  } else if (this.targetRotation < this.clientRotation) {
    this.clientRotation = (lessThan180) ? this.clientRotation - this.RotationSpeed : this.clientRotation + this.rotationSpeed; 
  }
  this.clientRotation = (this.clientRotation > Math.PI) ? this.clientRotation - Math.PI*2 : this.clientRotation + Math.PI*2; 
}
```

Your original code may seem over complicated, but I actually think you did a great job documenting your code through comments and making the code clear and readable. The only nitpick-y thing that I would recommend changing, no matter what (even if you arent a fan of ternaries), is using 'if'/'else-if''s instead of 'if' then another 'if' conditional. This is because both 'if' conditionals will be ran no matter what, while in the 'if'/'else-if' if the 'if' statement conditional succeeds then the 'else-if' conditional will not be checked and skipped over, so it is more efficient.

Comment: I do use ternaries often too, but I personally find the code clearer without them in some cases though. Good point for the else-ifs :)